# Translation strings as keys in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I read the documentation for translation strings on [Retrieving Translation Strings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#retrieving-translation-strings) but somehow I don't understand how to apply it.

Let's say I would like to render in a view `posts.index` the message *"I like programming"* in English, German ("*Ich mag Programmieren*") or Spanish ("*Me encanta programar*"), depending on the localization set by App::setLocale().

How would the translation files look like and how would I setup the view?

Answer (score 13):

I finally understood the concept. Within `resources/lang` you create a translation JSON file for every language, e. g.:

```
/resources
    /lang
        /de.json
        /es.json
```

There is no need to create an `en.json` file as `en` will be the default language if you don't set a language with `App::setLocale()`.

de.json:

```
{
     "I love programming.": "Ich mag programmieren."
}
```

es.json:

```
{
     "I love programming.": "Me encanta programar."
}
```

Next, you set in your controller the language via `App::setLocale();` and now comes the fun part. In the view, you only include the key of the JSON, e. g.

`{{ __('I love programming.') }}`

and depending on your localization, Laravel will automatically load the correct translation.

Comment: I am wondering if there are pre-made json files for common languages like Spanish. Although I speak Spanish fluently, I'm the lead dev on a very large project and the idea of spending so much time creating essentially a dictionary seems not to be a wise idea.

Answer (score 13):

I'd recommend to stay away from using translation strings and use keys instead:

1. Keys contain context information: `main-screen.dialog.add-item-button` - you know that this is a button on the main screen. This is much better than working with a string `Add Item`.
2. An editor like [BabelEdit](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit) displays the keys as tree. This makes it much easier to edit a particular subset of your translations. Using strings you easily end up with a list like `Abort`, `Add item`, `Alabama`, `Alaska`, `All`, `Arizona`,..
3. You can use different translations for different positions of the same text. E.g. for a form label you can create a shorter translation if you don't have enough space in a language.
4. You don't have to update all translation files if your main languages changes. E.g. if you add decide to change `Hello world.` to `Hello world!` you don't have to update all your files.

Comment: I was in doubt which approach to take. This is such a helpful comment. Great arguments, great advice.

Answer (score 4):

Store your language files within `resources/lang`, and structure would be like this.

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            messages.php
        /es
            messages.php
```

All language files simply return an array of keyed strings. For example:

```php
<?php

return [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
];
```

Then you've to define your route where you capture your locale and set it. like this

```php
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    // your code here
});
```

And then simply use `dot notation` to print with `{{ __() }}` or use `@lang()`

```html
{{ __('messages.welcome') }}

<!-- OR -->

@lang('messages.welcome')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick follow up. Actually, this approach is also clear to me. What I didn't understand was the approach to use translation strings as keys. But finally, I got the point and added an answer.

Comment: @Andreas That's Great :-)

Answer (score 1):

Messages (you can choose) is the name of your translation file.

For each language, you make a dir in the lang folder. Spanish is es.

```
{{ trans('messages.cool') }}
```

[image]

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the quick follow up. Actually, this approach is also clear to me. What I didn't understand was the approach to use translation strings as keys. But finally, I got the point and added an answer.